# Bash Output to Location

Tags: macos, bash

This script outputs a sparse disk image. I'd like place the image in the correct place on the system but don't know how to give it a location. I'd prefer not to move it post creation.

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname=`hostname -s`
mac=`ifconfig en0 | grep ether | tr -d ":" | awk {'print $2'}`
hdiutil create -size 300g -type SPARSE -fs HFS+ "$hostname"_"$mac"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/Volume/location/"$hostname"_"$mac"
```

worked